# How do I view python files in bitbucket?

Tags: python, bitbucket

I have committed my python file myfilename.ipynb in a git repository. 
But when I am trying to view my pull request in bitbucket, it shows like below:

[image]

Isn't there a nice view to python files like below in bitbucket?

[image]

Comment: `ipnb` suffix suggests you are pushing Jupyter notebooks (`.ipynb`) to your repository. Save the files as Python scripts and then push to BitBucket.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai thank you for the answer. I committed the Python script file and I am able to view it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

`ipynb` files (not `ipnb`) are **IPy**thon **N**ote**b**ook files, not Python source files (and internally, they're JSON files containing cells which may contain e.g. Python source or images or other data).

While e.g. GitHub has rich preview and diff for notebooks, BitBucket might not.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just committed and it looks pretty cool in bitbucket though.